# Удаление элемента массива и выдача случайного элемента в строку

Tags: javascript, массивы, случайные-числа, randomaccessfile

Я совсем новичок и имею проблемы с синтаксисом и русским языком . Помогите сделать чтобы программа загружала список имен из массив и при нажатии на кнопку которую вы увидите справа от имен Это имя удаляется из массива... Далее из массива имен берется случайное и выдается в строку снизу от кнопки... возможно вы посчитаете что я идиот, знайте что это правда ...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <title>Fucking wheel</title>
</head>
<body onload="descargarNombres()">

   <ul>
        <li id='namesAll'>
        </li>
   </ul>
  <button id="btn">Elegir</button>
</body>
<div class="line">  
</div>



<script type="text/javascript">

console.log('hola, amigüitos')


var names = [' Yeray',' Vlad',' Unai',' Sergio',' Naiara',' Sehili',' Saadi',' Yassine',' Melanie',' María',' Luis',' Jose',' Imanol',' Haimar',' Gontzal',' Elbo',' Diego',' César O.',' César C.',' Antonia',' Andoni']

function descargarNombres(){

  for (i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
      document.getElementById('namesAll').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<li>' + names[i] + '<a id="btn_delete" href="javascript:deleteName"><img src="img/remove.png" alt="delete" width="13px"></img></a></li>')
  }



}

// function delete name 

  a.oneclick = function deleteName (index){ 
let removed = names.splice(index,1) 
}


//button elegir
     let btn = document.getElementById("btn")

btn.addEventListener("click",function (event) {

     
     let randomN = Math.floor(Math.random()* 21)
    console.log(randomN)
     let result = names[randomN]
    console.log(result)

     document.getElementByClassName("line")[0].innerHTML= result 

   })
 console.log('random nombre sale')

</script>




</html>
```

Comment: _Далее из массива имен берется случайное и выдается в строку снизу от кнопки..._ можно подробнее?

Answer (score 1):

**Код, согласно тому, что я понял из описания:**

```js
var names = [' Yeray', ' Vlad', ' Unai', ' Sergio', ' Naiara', ' Sehili', ' Saadi', ' Yassine', ' Melanie', ' María', ' Luis', ' Jose', ' Imanol', ' Haimar', ' Gontzal', ' Elbo', ' Diego', ' César O.', ' César C.', ' Antonia', ' Andoni'];

var items = [];

var list = document.querySelector('ul');

function createItems() {
  names.forEach((el) => {
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    var button = document.createElement('button');
    button.addEventListener('click', removeName)
    button.innerText = 'delete';
    div.innerText = el;
    li.append(div, button);
    items.push(li);
  })
}

function showItems() {
  items.forEach(item => {
    list.append(item);
  })
}

function removeName(e) {
  names = names.filter(name => {
    return name.trim() != e.target.previousElementSibling.innerText
  })
  e.target.previousElementSibling.innerText = '';
  e.target.removeEventListener('click', removeName);
  appendRandomNameBelowButton(getRandomNameFromArray(), e.target.parentNode);
}

function getRandomNameFromArray() {
  var n = Math.floor(Math.random() * names.length);
  return names[n];
}

function appendRandomNameBelowButton(name, parent) {
  var span = document.createElement('span');
  span.innerText = name;
  parent.append(span)
}

createItems();
showItems();
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul {
  margin: auto;
  width: 20%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

li {
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "name button" "name randomName";
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

div {
  word-break: break-all;
  grid-area: name;
}

button {
  grid-area: button;
}

span {
  grid-area: randomName;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<ul></ul>
```

**На всякий случай:**

```js
var names = [' Yeray', ' Vlad', ' Unai', ' Sergio', ' Naiara', ' Sehili', ' Saadi', ' Yassine', ' Melanie', ' María', ' Luis', ' Jose', ' Imanol', ' Haimar', ' Gontzal', ' Elbo', ' Diego', ' César O.', ' César C.', ' Antonia', ' Andoni'];

var items = [];

var list = document.querySelector('ul');

function showItems() {
  clearList();

  items.forEach(item => {
    list.append(item);
  })
}


function createItems() {
  names.forEach((el) => {
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    var button = document.createElement('button');
    button.addEventListener('click', removeItem)
    button.innerText = 'delete';
    div.innerText = el;
    li.append(div, button);
    items.push(li);
  })
}

function removeItem(e) {
  items = items.filter(item => {
    return item != e.target.parentNode
  })
  showItems();
}

function clearList() {
  while (list.firstChild) {
    list.removeChild(list.firstChild);
  }
}

createItems();
showItems();
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul {
  margin: auto;
  width: 20%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

li {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

div {
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<ul></ul>
```